# A specific Google Talk account isn't going online with Telepathy client on KDE

Tags: linux, kde, instant-messaging, google-talk

I have some problems using a Google Talk account with Telepathy for KDE. I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 and KDE 4.10.2.

I use Telepathy with multiple accounts, also some other Google Talk ones, and everything works right except for this particular account.

The problem is that it can't get connected; everytime that I try to bring it online, I get a message like *"It wasn't possible to connect with {my-user-account}@gmail.com. A network error has occurred, please check you connection"* (I have roughly translated it from italian, my system default language; the exact wording might be different from english version, but the meaning should be clear nonetheless).

Like I said I also have other Google Talk accounts working on Telepathy without any problems, and the said account is working fine on other clients like Kopete, Thunderbird or Pidgin, so it seems that it's not an issue from the server side.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem was so silly (and so obviously solvable) that I'm almost embarassed by having had that issue.

Quoting from the [KDE Community Wiki](http://community.kde.org/KTp/Troubleshooting)

> **I keep being told "Authentication Failed"**
>
> Make sure you have telepathy-auth-handler installed.
>   Do you have Empathy installed? If so remove it.
>   Also check all the steps in the following section.

`telepathy-auth-handler` was present in my system, and Empathy is not installed, so I went on:

> **Google Talk disconnects with Network Error shortly after connecting**
>
> You need to check if your avatar (user picture) is small enough. Maximum file size allowed is 8192 bytes, maximum allowed dimensions for avatars are 96x96.

After having changed the avatar picture to a proper one, the account  works properly.